# Passing values on annotation tap - iphone google map SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-maps, dictionary

I am using google map SDK to display places in my iphone app.
On taping the annotation I am navigating to place's detail page.For that I have to pass the values of that place

Currently I am using

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker {

 DetailViewController *Detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

     Detail.address=marker.snippet;
     Detail.name = marker.title;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:Detail animated:YES];


}
```

But I want to pass more values,how to do that ?

Comment: which values you want to pass ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no need of tough methods.It is clear in the documentation that we can pass any data through annotation.userData

assign the details like this...

```
   options.title = @"Some Title";
    options.userData = @"data"; // you can assign any data to this like NSData,String,Array etc
   options.snippet =@"Some thing";
```

and pass these data like this

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker {
    DetailViewController *Detail = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@" DetailViewController" bundle:nil];


   Detail.data=marker.userData;  // passing the data

[self.navigationController pushViewController:restDetail animated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set more Propery like snippet,title in GMSMarker Class based on that you can pass more values in DetailViewController Class like address ,name.

Hope, You understand what i am trying to say !!!

Comment: Thank you for replay.But no need for that we can easily pass that.I gave the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think what Dipak is trying to say is to add more Class behind `marker` like `(Class)method`. You might need brackets for it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way be setting a value for a key for the marker:

```
marker.setValue("20", forKey: "id")
```

and you can get it later using :

```
marker.value(forKey: "id")
```

---

**Or**

My way to do it is by create an extension for the GMSMarker and using the userData property to make the GMSMarker fits my need, for me I want to add each marker with instance of Branch class (map with markers for branches of some company) and this is the way that I did:

```
extension GMSMarker {
    var branch: Branch {
        set(branch) {
            self.userData = branch
        }

        get {
           return self.userData as! Branch
       }
   }
}
```

so when I set the marker property I set it like this:

```
marker.branch = someBranch
```

Isn't that clearer and more readable than marker.userData = someBranch ??